# How to get ngtemplate-loader working with Webpack 3, Angular 1, TypeScript and ES 6 modules?

Tags: angularjs, webpack-2

I am trying configure ngtemplate-loader to be able to use my angular template in a TypeScript file like so:

```
import myTemplateUrl from './hello-angular2-template.thtml';
angular
    .module('pd')
    .component('helloAngular2', {
        templateUrl: myTemplateUrl,
    });
```

Loader definition in webpack.config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        // Angular Template HTML
        {
            test: /\.thtml$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'ngtemplate-loader',
                },
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                }
            ],
        },
```

(The strange *.ththml suffix is just so, that no standard html-loader can interfere.)

However the template never gets loaded (is undefined after import).

I tried to add

```
options: {
    exportAsEs6Default: true
}
```

to the chained html-loader, but that did not work out, too.

**Full example project**: https://github.com/eekboom/ng-webpack

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is a bug/missing feature in ngtemplate-loader.

I created an issue:

https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader/issues/63

and a pull request that fixes it

https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader/pull/64

Hope it gets accepted soon. For now I can point my package.json to the commit containing the fix in my fork.

Comment: Why is it stuck?

Answer (score 2):

I made it work with this settings:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'ngtemplate-loader',
      options: {
        angular: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: 'raw-loader',
    },
  ],
};
```

**The packages versions:**

```
"webpack": "^3.5.0",
"angular": "^1.6.5",
"ngtemplate-loader": "^2.0.1",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
```

Comment: To add to this answer I had to add `options: { esModule: false}` to `raw-loader` to get it running .

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it work is to use `import * as templateUrl from './../..';`:

```
import * as myTemplateUrl from './hello-angular2-template.thtml';

angular
    .module('pd')
    .component('helloAngular2', {
        templateUrl: myTemplateUrl,
    });
```

`import.d.ts` definition:

```
declare module '*.thtml' {
    var _: string;
    export = _;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours. this is what solved for me:

changing from:

```
import myTemplateUrl from './hello-angular2-template.thtml';
```

to:

```
import * as myTemplateUrl from './hello-angular2-template.thtml';
```

adding the "* as" solved everything if someone stuck with this too.